# IBM Liberty issue

Tags: ibm-was

An architect is having issues bringing Liberty up.  Currently,  an individual is running a server on his  local computer and they want to move it to a shared server.  When he tries to deploy a simple “helloworld” it’s failing and he is receiving an error “Context Root Not Found”.   He is not sure what to set in server.xml file to have wlp recognize the application.  They have ODM 8.5 on the mainframe.  He thinks it might help if he saw an example of an EAR or WAR file deployed.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Either put your application in the `dropins` folder, it will be detected and started automatically, or put it in the apps folder and configure in `server.xml` like this:

```
<webApplication id="HelloApp" location="HelloApp.war" name="HelloApp"/>
```

by default context root is application file name without extension, but you can change it by adding `contextRoot="mycontext"` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, We tried the above and received - Java NoSuchElement Exception while deploying WAR file. But not able to figure out which element was missing as there was no full details about exception.

Comment: @Brian, add your `server.xml` to the question.